# Navigation Bar disappears upon window resizing

Tags: html, css, web

I am currently trying to build my first website, and mainly using HTML5/CSS3, I have come across as issue that I'm sure is simply solved but struggling.

My homepage is working as desired apart from the Nav Bar, when i shrink the window down, all elements such as the hgroup, footer, and main sections become scrollable.

My Nav bar however disappears when I either:

a. Zoom in too much
b. make the window small enough.

Is this easily solved?

Many Thanks

Heres my HTML(please be forgiving, i'm a real newbie):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
    <title>Worthworks Signage</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">                <!--WRAP  ENTIRE DOCUMENT-->

<header>    

        <a href="index.html">
        <img class="logo" src="images/logos/300pxbluegradient.jpg" alt="Worth Works Signage">
        </a>

        <hgroup>
            <h1><span class="blueText">Worth</span>works Signage</h1>
            <h2>Sign Design – <span class="blueText">Manufacture </span>– Installation – <span class="blueText">Refurbishment </span>– Advice</h2>
        </hgroup>

        <nav>                                       <!--START OF NAVIGATION-->
        <div id='cssmenu'>
            <ul>

                <li class='active'><a href='index.html'><span>Home</span></a></li>

                <li class='has-sub'><a href='products.html'><span>Products</span></a> <!--PRODUCTS-->

                    <ul>
                        <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Signs</span></a> <!--PRODUCT SUB #1-->
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href='#'><span>Castings</span></a></li>
                                <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Item</span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Casting</span></a> <!--PRODUCT SUB #2-->
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Item</span></a></li>
                                <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Item</span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Site Work</span></a> <!--PRODUCT SUB #3-->
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Item</span></a></li>
                                <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Item</span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li><a href='gallery.html'><span>Gallery</span></a></li> <!--GALLERY-->

                <li><a href='testimonials.html'><span>Testimonials</span></a></li> <!--TESTIMONIALS-->

                <li><a href='contact.html'><span>Contact</span></a></li> <!--CONTACT US-->

                <li class='last'><a href='about.html'><span>About Us</span></a></li> <!--ABOUT US-->
            </ul>
        </div>      
        </nav>

</header>   
                                                <!--END OF HEADER-->



                                                <!--END OF NAVIGATION-->

                                                <!-- START OF SECTION-->
<div id="section-wrap">
    <div id="mainimage">Main Image Goes Here</div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
    <div id="brochure">Order your <a href="brochure.html"><u>FREE</u></a> Brochure today</div>
    <div id="testimonals">SEE what our satisfied customers think..</div>
</div>
                                                <!-- END OF SECTION-->


<div style="clear:both"></div>

                                                <!-- START OF FOOTER-->
<footer>
    <div id="wrap">
        <div class="left footercol">
        <h3 class="foothead">Connect</h3>
            <div class="footcontent">
            <ul>
                <li class="facebook"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/worthworkssignage">Facebook</a></li>
                <li class="twitter"><a href="http://www.twitter.com/WorthWorksSigns">Twitter</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>  <!--End of Column Content Div-->
        </div>      <!--End of Footer Column-->
```

And here is my CSS3:

```
*{
margin: 0 auto;
text-align:left;
}

body{
margin:0 0 300px;
width: 100%;
height:1200px;
padding:0;
font-size:13px;
font-family:helvetica neue,helvetica,arial, sans-serif;
color:#000000;
background-color: #cccccc;
}

#container{
min-height:100%;
border:1px solid black;
position:relative;
}

/* HEADER STYLING*/

header{
height:410px;
padding:0;
width:1580px;
background-color:#ffffff;
clear:both;
}

.logo{ 
display:inline;                       
margin:20px;
width:20%;
float:left;
padding:10px;
}

hgroup{
font-family:Baker Signet, Gills Sans Light;
padding-bottom:20px;
}

h1{
display:inline-block;
font-size:100px;
padding: 160px 0px 25px 10px;
color:#A1A1A1;
float:left;
}

h2{
clear:both;
display:inline-block;
font-size:28px;
padding-left:15px;
color:#A1A1A1;
float:center;
}

.blueText{
color:#4cb6ea;
font:
}   
/*NAV BAR*/

nav{
width:1580px;
height:46px;
position:relative;
}

#cssmenu {
background-color: #4cb6ea;
margin: 0;
width: 1580px;
padding: 0;
line-height: 1;
border-top: 3px solid  #4cb6ea;
display:inline-block;
position: relative;
font-family: Hallo Sans, sans-serif;
}

#cssmenu ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  width:1540px;
}
#cssmenu ul:after {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
}

#cssmenu ul li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width:12%;
}
#cssmenu ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-transition: color .2s ease;
  -moz-transition: color .2s ease;
  -ms-transition: color .2s ease;
  -o-transition: color .2s ease;
  transition: color .2s ease;
}
#cssmenu ul li ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
  top: auto;
}
#cssmenu ul li ul li {
  max-height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 0.4s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: max-height 0.4s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: max-height 0.4s ease-out;
  -o-transition: max-height 0.4s ease-out;
  transition: max-height 0.4s ease-out;
  background: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu ul li ul li.has-sub:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #000000;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 13px;
  right: 15px;
}
#cssmenu ul li ul li.has-sub:before {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  border-left-color: #ffffff;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 15px;
  right: 15px;
}
#cssmenu ul li ul li a {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: none;
  color: #000000;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 140px;
  padding: 11px 10px 11px 20px;
}
#cssmenu ul li ul li:hover > a,
#cssmenu ul li ul li.active > a {
  color: #4cb6ea;
}
#cssmenu ul li ul li:hover:after,
#cssmenu ul li ul li.active:after {
  background: #4cb6ea;
}
#cssmenu ul li ul li:hover > ul {
  left: 170px;
  top: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul li ul li:hover > ul > li {
  max-height: 72px;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  background: #ffffff;
  -webkit-transition: height .2s;
  -moz-transition: height .2s;
  -ms-transition: height .2s;
  -o-transition: height .2s;
  transition: height .2s;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a {
  padding-right: 40px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  background: #ffffff;
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 13px;
  right: 14px;
  top: 16px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  border: 4px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #4cb6ea;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 16px;
  top: 21px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover:after,
#cssmenu > ul > li.active:after {
  height: 100%;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a {
  color: #000000;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a:after,
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a:after {
  background: #000000;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a:before,
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a:before {
  border-top-color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > ul {
  left: 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > ul > li {
  max-height: 72px;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  display: none;
}
@media all and (max-width: 768px), only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  #cssmenu > ul {
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.35s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: max-height 0.35s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: max-height 0.35s ease-out;
    -o-transition: max-height 0.35s ease-out;
    transition: max-height 0.35s ease-out;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul.open {
    max-height: 1000px;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(110, 110, 110, 0.25);
  }
  #cssmenu ul {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #cssmenu ul > li {
    float: none;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li a {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul > li:after {
    display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li.has-sub > a:after,
  #cssmenu ul li.has-sub > a:before,
  #cssmenu ul li ul li.has-sub:after,
  #cssmenu ul li ul li.has-sub:before {
    display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li ul,
  #cssmenu ul li ul li ul,
  #cssmenu ul li ul li:hover > ul {
    left: 0;
    position: relative;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li ul li,
  #cssmenu ul li:hover > ul > li {
    max-height: 999px;
    position: relative;
    background: none;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li ul li a {
    padding: 8px 20px 8px 35px;
    color: #ffffff;
    width: auto;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li ul ul li a {
    padding: 8px 20px 8px 50px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li ul li:hover > a {
    color: #000000;
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button {
    display: block;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #ffffff;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button:after {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 3px;
    width: 22px;
    border-top: 2px solid #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff;
    right: 20px;
    top: 16px;
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button:before {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 3px;
    width: 22px;
    border-top: 2px solid #ffffff;
    right: 20px;
    top: 26px;
  }
  }

/*MAIN CONTENT STYLING*/


#section-wrap {
    width:1580px;
    height:1200px;
}

#mainimage {  
    background:#fff;
    width:1580px;
    height:1000px;
    color:#A1A1A1;
}

#brochure {
    float:left;
    background:#fff;  
    width:787px;
    height:342px;
    color:#A1A1A1;
    border-top: 4px solid #4cb6ea;
    border-right: 3px solid #4cb6ea;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #4cb6ea;
}

#testimonals {
    float:right;
    background:#fff;
    width:787px;
    height:342px;
    color:#A1A1A1;
    border-top: 4px solid #4cb6ea;
    border-left: 3px solid #4cb6ea;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #4cb6ea;
}
```

[What i have done till now](http://jsbin.com/zuwipubi/1/edit)

Comment: your footer element isn't closed in your example code. please use http://jsbin.com/ and provide a link here.

Comment: Thanks here is my code and CSS http://jsbin.com/zuwipubi/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: well your css is a complete mess. anyway, the problem with the disappearing menu is that you have a `media query` in your code, i suspect for mobile purposes, and it changes things when the width of the pages gets to some point. look at the CSS line with `@media all and (max-width: 768px)` and below..

Comment: thank you, yes the CSS needs to be sorted through i'm just learning as i go, the #cssmenu was found online, i need to line by line it and sort it through, thank you for your help.

Comment: Personally this sounds like a useful feature I'd like to take advantage of.

Answer (score 0):

In your @media query, you have the following CSS declaration:

```
#cssmenu > ul {max-height: 0}
```

This is the line that's hiding your navigation, your giving it a maximum height of 0px.

Comment: I can change the value here to say 46px, to match the height of the Nav Bar, and upon a resize only the "Home" button is visible, progress sure.

Comment: That isn't true, this is only small part of the problem. you just need to delete ALL the media queries if you don't want things to change as you resize the browser.